# Write to remote file using SSH

Tags: java, ssh, scp, jsch

I want to write a String generated by a POJO to be written to a file in a remote server accessible only through scp/ssh.
Would like to avoid creating local temporary file and scp the files to the remote machines.
Implementation using Jsch library is preferred.

Comment: You can write the String directly to an OutputStream, but since a String contains chars and not bytes, you must decide on an encoding (charset) to convert the String's chars to bytes.  When in doubt, use `string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: You should consider using sftp and [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html). It has functions to open a remote file which return an `OutputStream` that you can write data to.

Comment: @Kenster your approach looks promising, I will explore this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Kenster's recommendation and ended up doing something like below.

```
session = jsch.getSession(user, agent, port);
session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
((ChannelSftp) channel).put(new ByteArrayInputStream(args[0].getBytes()), args[1]);
```